# Common table expression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I ve a table named as tbl_Emp:

[image]

Now I want to select Unique Emp_Name with EmpID and EmpSalary as follows.I just want to know that what will be the Common table expression in SQL to do this.

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple query using `CTE`

```
WITH CTE AS(   
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY EmpID) AS ROWNO,    
                    EmpID,EmpName, EmpSalary FROM tbl_emp
) 
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, EmpSalary  FROM CTE WHERE ROWNO = 1 order by EmpID
```

If you want Remove the duplicate data use the script as bellow

```
WITH CTE AS(   
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY EmpID) AS ROWNO,    
                        EmpID, EmpName, EmpSalary FROM tbl_emp
    ) 
    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE ROWNO > 1
```

I think the query can help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need for a CTE on this.  I would `JOIN` the table with itself.  Something like:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tbl_Emp t
INNER JOIN
(
  select MIN(EmpID) FirstEmp from tbl_Emp group by EmpName
) t2
ON t2.FirstEmp=t.EmpID;
```

Basically, I'm joining in a second table that has the *lowest* `EmpID` field of each distinct `EmpName`, then selecting all rows that match one of those `EmpID` fields.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16c40/1)

Comment: Great it works. Now If I want to remove duplicate records from tbl_Emp what will be the simplest SQL query?

Comment: I think you should post this as a new question.  But I'd do a bit of research first, since there are _many_ duplicates.  If my answer meets your criteria, please hit the _Accept_ button.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for DISTINCT.

something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Emp_Name, EmpID, EmpSalary
FROM tbl_emp;
```

Comment: This would just display every row.